# How to change background position using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, facebook

How can I allow users to change their profile cover position like Facebook and Twitter using jQuery and dragging? Also, how can I get their saved position?

Comment: There is too less information in your question. Show some code or describe in more detail. Otherwise you will get no answer I guess.

Comment: just want to know how to allow user to change background position, same like facebook cover so position can set by users

Comment: It is about cropping part of the image, check these examples  http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php

Comment: i want like this one http://keith-wood.name/backgroundPos.html ,click on position tab, but i need it by mouse dragging ?